# How to fetch the data from REST API inside ListView.builder() in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and trying to fetch the data from the REST API but get the error `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value).`

```
 List<User>? user;
```

```
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: user?.length,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [Text(user![index].firstName)],
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
```

here I performing an operation on a variable that is `null`. I have defined `itemCount: user?.length` and `Text(user![index].firstName)` to handle this but I get error like this

[image: error]

how to fix this?

Comment: You can try `Text(user?[index].firstName?? "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
itemCount: user?.length
```

the operatnd ?. means that it will return the length or null if user is null, if itemCount is null it will build infinity until the itemBuilder returns null too.

```
user![index].firstName
```

It means that you're sure user is not null and by doing that the index will return a not null value. This is a contradiction because you're not sure if its null in the cunter, but you're sure that is not in the builder:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: user?.length ?? 0, ///This tells the builder there are no items in case the user is null, so itemBuilder will not iterate
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    ....
  },
);
```

Now it will not report an error, but it will be empty until you fix your user variable to not be null.